# How should I ignore the char in URL asp.net MVC?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

Please, give me an advice on the following question: there's a usual string like here :  /Search/Index, and a user inputs a char accidentally: /Search/Index'. How should I ignore the сhar and make a user simply follow the link Search/Index?

Comment: you must config routing configurations to ignore cases.

Comment: But there may be many cases ... or can be reduced to one? Sorry for my english.

Comment: That listed in Global.asax or RouteConfig file. that's very simple and easy to understand and changable by you.

Comment: Yes, I want to ignore symbol

Comment: I must mention that there is main difrence between actions that ended with some additional unwanted characters. That can be : 1-alphabet/numeric that can change action name 2-meaningful like URL encoded/decoded 3-meaningless I think you want to remove meaningless ones. true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can add this code block in your Global.asax file.

The line "{controller}/{action*}/{id}"  have `{action*}` so action will be `index` and any characters after `index` will consider as ignored and route to the `index` action.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) {
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action*}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Search", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
    );
}
```

Comment: how to ignore characters (') in the URL?

Comment: So '*' after `action` solves that? have you ever tested that?

Comment: @AmirHosseinMehrvarzi Yes It is working fine and I have tested it.

Comment: @SergeyYanchenko you can try this.It is working for me

Comment: @BhaveshKachhadiya how it filters according to my last comment followed in question?

Comment: The reason this works (I suspect) is due the * symbol being the wildcard in the situation. This is pretty common among different tech situations, and you can see it being used similarly in the IgnoreRoute.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not advisable. This would result in multiple urls for the same ressource and your searchengine ranking might suffer. It might be better to just return a 404

http://moz.com/blog/canonical-url-tag-the-most-important-advancement-in-seo-practices-since-sitemaps